# PHP syntax error showing since moving to new server

Tags: php, apache

I have just transferred my site over to a dedicated server and all was working fine before but since moving to the new server, all pages seem to be fine except for 1 thats giving me a white screen. A check on the error log says PHP Parse error:

> syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/ftp1/www/yp_admin/products.php
>   on line 112

This is line 112

```
} while ($row_subcategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($subcategories));
```

and the complete section of the code is

```
<? if (isset($_GET['catid'])) {

            $scatid1 = $_GET['scatid'];

            do { ?>
                <div class="div"><a <?php if ($row_subcategories['id'] == $scatid1) { echo('style="color:orange;"'); } ?> href="?view&catid=<?php echo($catid) ?>&scatid=<?php echo($row_subcategories['id']); ?>"><?php echo($row_subcategories['sub_category']); ?></a><span><a href="?new&catid=<?php echo($catid); ?>&scatid=<?php echo($row_subcategories['id']); ?>"> New Product</a></span> </div>
                <?php } while ($row_subcategories = mysql_fetch_assoc($subcategories));


                } else { 

                do { ?>
            <a href="?catid=<?php echo($row_categories['id']); ?>">
                <div class="div"><?php echo($row_categories['category']); ?></div>
            </a>
                <?php } while ($row_categories = mysql_fetch_assoc($categories));}

                ?>
```

It was working completely fine before an I cannot find any errors, Have any of you come across this before?

Thanks in advance for your help.

FYI I am running CentOS with Apache server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:-

```
<? if (isset($_GET['catid'])) {
```

with

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['catid'])) {
```

In your old server `php.ini` file must have been configured in such a way so as to allow short tags.

Answer (score 5):

Try to start your opening tag in the very first line with `<?php` instead of `<?`. Short tags are now disallowed.

**EDIT** More reading [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Answer (score 2):

Probably on your old server you had default settings for `short_open_tag`.

You need to enable `short_open_tag = 1` on your php ini file. Because your new server has this setting turned off.